# Sqlalchemy print the output object of a query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been searching but can't find anything ...

My model is,

```
class Departament(db.Model):

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    departament = Column(String, unique=True)
    depmv = relationship('Mvpordep', backref='line', lazy='select')
    depfac = relationship('Bill', backref='line_fac', lazy='select')

    def __init__(self, departament):

        self.departament = departament

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.departament)
```

and y try

```
departament = Departament.query.filter_by(departament='ti').first()

print(departament.id)
```

but it gives me the following error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

When I get multiple rows and iterate it with a for loop, no problem. But if I try to do it with a for loop, the logical thing happens

```
for out in departament:
    print(out.id)
```

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I don't understand what happens

Comment: Change this line from 'Departament.query.filter_by(departament='ti').first()' to 'Departament.objects.filter_by(departament='ti').first()'

Comment: No luck ```AttributeError: type object 'Departament' has no attribute 'objects'```

Comment: Your actual model name is **Departmento** not only Department there is an ‘o’ in the last

Comment: Yes, you are correct, excuse me. It was an error when writing the post.

Thank you very much for the tip.

Finally I have already found the problem. It was in that the dev database and the production one were different, and that data did not exist in dev.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using  `__repr__()` function in your department class. So if you fetch data from department class you will only get data of department(as you created).

Here the error is, there is no id in your fetched data it's only department. So that why you get `Nonetype` error.

If you want all data from department class, remove  `__repr__()` function (and `__init__()`) from department class or declare every column name in your  `__repr__()` function (and `__init__()`).